# Let a and b be real numbers such that 0 < a < b. Prove $\frac{a+b}2 > \sqrt{ab} > \frac{2ab}{a + b}$

Tags: proof-writing

Let a and b be real numbers such that 0 < a < b. Prove $\frac{a+b}2 > \sqrt{ab} > \frac{2ab}{a + b}$

How can I prove this? Been working for hours and got nowhere. I see $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $\frac{2ab}{a + b}$ are almost reciprocals. Is this important?

Please explain step by step.

Comment: Square the inequalities. Then use $0 <(a-b)^2 = a^2-2ab+b^2$.

Comment: http://www.academia.edu/7616078/Prove_of_A.M._G.M._H.M

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize the AM GM HM correlation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

The left-hand side inequality is equivalent  to $a+b-2\sqrt{ab}$.

For the right-hand side, replace $a$ and $b$ with $\dfrac1a$ and $\dfrac1b$ in the first inequality.

Comment: How do I prove $a + b - 2\sqrt{ab}$ is positive?

Comment: Set $x=\sqrt a, y=\sqrt b$.

Answer (score 0):

first we show that$ (a+b)\over 2$ > $\sqrt {ab}$

i.e. T.S. $a+b \gt2 \sqrt {ab}$

i.e. T.S. $(a+b)^2 \gt 4ab$

i.e. T.S. $a^2+b^2 \gt2ab$

i.e.T.S. $(a-b)^2 >0$

which is true.

Similarly you can prove another inequality.

Answer (score 0):

There are some relations between Arithmetic Mean, Geometric Mean and Harmonic Mean.

A.M. ≥ G.M. ≥ H.M.      &      A.M. × H.M. = G.M.^2

[Prove of A.M.≥G.M.≥H.M.](https://www.academia.edu/7616078/Prove_of_A.M._G.M._H.M)

Comment: Small correction: $AM \times HM = GM^2$.